# Find all lines touched by author and also containing a string in Git

Tags: git

Is there any way I can scan the entire repo for lines that are touched by a specific author and also contain a certain string?

For example, let's say one author has used the wrong db field in his code, which is spread out in many files. The wrong db field is used in many commits by the same author, and is used correctly in other commits by other authors. Now we need to change it in all lines in all files which were written by this author, but not for lines which were written by other authors.

So we have have author A and author B, and 2 files.

a.cpp:

```
use1(my_db_field); // author A
use5(some_other_field); // author A
use2(my_db_field); // author B
```

b.cpp:

```
use3(my_db_field); // author B
use4(my_db_field); // author A
```

So if I search for lines changed by author A and `my_db_field`, I need to get both the lines with `use1()` and `use4()`, but not `use3()`, `use2()`, or `use5()`.

Preferably, we want to search for the string with ignore case and regex enabled.

Is this possible to do in Git?

Comment: `blame` and `grep` ??

Comment: @OSryx Can  blame print all the files? I thought it was one file only. I don't know which files exactly may be touched in the repo.

Comment: `blame` works file by file :s sorry

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an easy way to do this.

You could use `git log --author=foo@bar --pretty:%H` to give a list of commits that the author has done, and then for each of those run a `git diff` against the parent and see if the diff has the change that you're looking for. But you'd have to brute force it.

`git blame` will only show you things on a file-by-file basis, and if you don't know which files to look for, this may not be useful. In addition it will hide changes where the author has made the mistake and then someone else has subsequently edited the same line.

Comment: Can I use `find ... xargs` or something like that to run blame on all the files? I'd need it to print to stdout though, so i can concatenate everything.

Comment: You can use `git grep` if you want to search the working directory, which will be faster than `find ... xargs` but this won't search history for you. You'll only catch lines where the author has made the error and no-one has edited the line subsequently, which didn't sound like it would meet your needs. If you're only looking at current state, `git grep` to find the files and then `git blame` on each would be fastest.

Comment: I found something that works for me - `git log --author=Jon -p`, and then searching through it for the text I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --author=Jon -G my_db_field
```

will show you commits by that author that touch lines containing that regex.